# Clustering Coefficient of Erdos Renyi Model

Tags: clustering, graph-theory

The clustering coefficient for erdos renyi model $G(n,p) = p$.

Now i have been studying in various papers that it cannot model real world networks which has high clustering coefficient. My question is that if we use a higher probability value for the model then we our clustering coefficient should increase then why cant we use this model for such real world networks like small world phenomenon ?

Comment: Side remark: for Geometric Random Graph clustering coefficient is known and depend only on dimension of space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph#Clustering_coefficient

Comment: What could that mean intuatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ER graph, density and clustering coefficient are equal. In most "real-world networks", they differ by orders of magnitude.

Therefore, if an ER graph has a realistic density, then it has not a realistic clustering coefficient; and if it has a realistic clustering coefficient, then it has not a realistic density.

This is actually a key element that makes ER graphs poor models for most real-world networks: in practice, **despite** a low density, the clustering coefficient if high. You are right in pointing the fact that a high clustering coefficient alone is easy to obtain.